# d3 Display Only Line Strings within Map Bounds

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to plot running routes on OpenStreetMap tiles in d3.js, which is not a problem when I'm displaying < 1,000 at a time, but I have over 100,000 routes. Since not all the routes are in the same geo-location, I want to only show the routes say in the metropolitan area of London at one time.

The problem that I'm running into is filtering before displaying on the map, i.e. finding the bounding box of the route given the defined projection and path; finding the route centroid; and then seeing if the projection contains the route centroid. I've been searching through the d3.js documentation but haven't been able to get this to work; does anyone have any suggestions on how best to tackle this?

```
// Sample projection and tile code for London
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0.1275, 51.5072])
    .scale((1 << 20) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([960 / 2, 500 / 2]);
var tiler = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([960, 500]);
var tilerData = tiler
    .scale(projection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
    .translate(projection([0, 0]));
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

// Data read in from CSV file - [id, date, encoded_poly]
d3.csv('data/gpsdata.csv', function (d) {

    // Is there a way to filter out the routes that are displayed on the visible map?

    var mapBounds = tilerData.getBounds();
    var filteredData = d.filter(function(e){
        var x = {type: "LineString", coordinates: decode(e.encPoly)};
        return mapBounds.contains(path(x).getBounds().getCenter());
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`path.centroid()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-path_centroid)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that works great for the route centroid...would you recommend using something like svg.getBBox() where svg is the container for the map or something else related to the path element for checking to see if the map contains the route centroid?

Comment: You don't even need to do that if you're setting width and height of the SVG yourself. Just compare the centroid coordinates to that size (modulo any translations you're doing).